# Heatmap log colour scale: caxis() doesn't map values correctly

Tags: matlab, heatmap, matlab-figure, colorbar

I have a 2D array with logarithmically distributed values from `[1e-5, 1e5]`. For various reasons, I want to change the colourbar with limits beyond this range. I do this using caxis, e.g. `caxis([a,b])`, where `a` and `b` are the desired exponents. However the resulting colourbar does not map correctly.

Example problem, starting with log-distributed values and desired limits of `[1e-5, 1e5]`:

```
% Create log values and generate heatmap
dim = 10;
x = logspace(-5,5,dim);
values = repmat(x,[dim,1]);
hm = heatmap(values);

% Make visually clearer
hm.GridVisible = 'off';
colormap default
ax1 = gca;
ax1.XDisplayLabels = nan(length(ax1.XDisplayData),1);
ax1.YDisplayLabels = nan(length(ax1.YDisplayData),1);

% Colour bar scaling - PROBLEM
set(gca,'ColorScaling','log') % Log scale
caxis([-5,5]) % Lower/Upper limits (exponents) (to change!)
ax2 = struct(gca);
cb = ax2.Colorbar;
cb.Ticks = [1e0,1e1,1e2,1e3,1e4,1e5]; % Example ticks to show problem...
```

After the limits are specified, the colour mapping becomes skewed. If you pause the code after the `set` line, the `caxis` values give `[-11.5, 11.5]`, not `[-5, 5]`. Therefore, if I desire a fixed colour range such as `[1e-7, 1e7]`, I apparently need to fudge the values. What's going on? Does `caxis` not define exponents in the way that it should?

Answer (score 2):

Solved answer via help on MATLAB Central. I was expecting that `caxis()` expects exponents in base 10, however it's of course expecting natural log exponents. Therefore, for a given colourbar range `[a,b]`, I simply need to type:

```
caxis(log([a,b]))
```